# Firefox 3.6 and above. Always show one tab even if all tabs are closed like Firefox 3.0

Tags: firefox-3.6

1. I very much got used to Firefox 3.0.
   In that, to free the memory, I close all tabs but still the main Firefox window does not close.
   But in Firefox 3.6 and later if I want to close all tabs and if I do so then Firefox totally exists. This is not the case with 3.0. How to stop Firefox from not closing the main process even if I close all threads (tabs)?
2. The autocomplete feature in the address bar of Firefox 3.6 and greater is in a dark blue color which makes me very much annoyed. With my environment and the monitor glare that is inducing anger in me, so how the color be changed to be like Firefox 3.0? Because you know that black and white are a neutral and good combination and since I have been working in Firefox 3.0 (and earlier versions) for a long time this new color change and other uncomfortable options are making me sick. 
   **To check CSS3 I need to use Firefox 3.5 and greater**. Besides I like Firefox because it includes the W3C's recommendations so I can learn and test new recomendations from W3C.

Comment: Please ask this kind of question on http://superuser.com/ StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Oh. but when i checked for tags i can see there are many for firefox. so is the reason for me to post here. that made me assure that i can post such questions here. Please notify me if i am wrong.

Comment: No: Your question is entirely on the use of Firefox, a browser, which is in no way connected to programming. The reason for the tag's existence is for a) Browser compatibility web development question and b) Firefox addon development questions

Comment: Oh. i got it. Thank you. I will do accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) By design. Still, the following setting should work as the name suggests: (type `about:config` in address bar and then make a search)

> browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab; **false**

(2) You need `re-branding`

Comment: Another missing option i found comparing to 3.0 and that is.
when i close an instance of firefox out of 3 or 4... that is.. when i close one window using alt+f+x all instances gets closed. i want only that instance to be close and all other windows be opened as in 3.0

Answer (score 0):

1. Try TAb Mix Plus add-on for more control over the way the tabs function
2. There are hundreds of themes available which modify the colors - you just have experiment until you find one you like. I still use the default and that does not have a dark blue bar.